# why given query is giving unexpected output?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table in MySql database contains a column named **department** with values `[HR,Admin,HR,Admin,Admin,Account,Account,Admin]`.

I want to fetch the unique values of **department** and print its length.

Query which I executed is:

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(DISTINCT department) from table`
```

Which is giving error.

But if I execute:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CHAR_LENGTH(department) from table
```

It is giving the correct output.

I want to know why the first query is giving the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    CHAR_LENGTH(DISTINCT department)
FROM table
```

Is giving you an error because `CHAR_LENGTH` takes a single value, `DISTINCT` is used for taking multiple values and returning only unique occurrences of that value. Using `DISTINCT` inside `CHAR_LENGTH` implies that CHAR_LENGTH will need to handle multiple values which it can't do and as a result it's an error.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CHAR_LENGTH(department)
FROM table
```

Has a different meaning, here we perform `CHAR_LENGTH` on each row in the table, then get the unique values for said length.

If you want to get the length of unique departments you can use `GROUP BY` to group all the departments into a single row, then return the `CHAR_LENGTH` of the department once it's a single row there which will preserve instances where multiple departments have the same length(like English and Spanish):

```
SELECT
    CHAR_LENGTH(department)
FROM table
GROUP BY
    department
```